# Powershell dll loading

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly

I have a Powershell script that calls a method in a C# library. The library dll is loaded as:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$automationHome\dll\abc.dll") | Out-Null
```

Now, my C# library uses another library xyz.dll in it. I believe I don't need to load this in Powershell script, since the abc.dll will resolve it. However, I am getting an error saying:

> Could not load file or assembly 'xyz, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LoadFrom()`  should ideally look for the `xyz.dll` in the same directory as `abc.dll`

If you are running the script from the same directory as the dlls, add the below and then do the `LoadFrom()`

```
$currentScriptDirectory = Get-Location
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($currentScriptDirectory.Path)
```

Comment: An alternate to get the current path is $PWD.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the dependency dll xyz is in the path that LoadLibrary will use.  I think in your case that will be anything local to the powershell script, anything in a sub directory of the power shell script, or anything in the path variable or in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

Does the reference to xyz.dll from abc.dll (add reference) have the specific version property set to true (default setting) and you are using a later version of xyz.dll?

For some assemblies the only way to get them to work is o load them into the GAC. You may want to try loading xyz into the GAC.

Comment: What does GAC stand for?

Comment: Global Assembly Cache 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache