# Could not load file or assembly 'AForge, Version=2.2.4.0, ... '

Tags: image-processing, powershell, powershell-2.0, aforge

I have no problems using AForge classes in a Windows Form application in Visual Studio.  I am now trying to use them in Windows PowerShell.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Program Files\AForge.NET\IPLab\References\AForge.NET\AForge.Imaging.dll')
```

gives:

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v2.0.50727     C:\Program Files\AForge.NET\IPLab\References\AForge.NET\AForge.Imaging.dll
```

It says v2.0.50727 even though the AForge.Imaging.dll File Version and Product Version are both 2.2.4.0.  But I have no problems executing the following to instantiate an AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage object $umi (where $bmdata is an Drawing.BitMapData object):

```
$umi = new-object Aforge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage $bmdata
```

But the moment I tried to access the $umi object, for example $umi.GetType(), I get the following error:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "GetType": "Could not load file or assembly 'AForge, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At line:1 char:13
+ $umi.GetType <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

What could be wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe one of the DLL:s that _AForge.NET_ is dependent upon cannot be found? Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6914080/650012) SO question and accepted answer, maybe this will help you

Comment: I looked at that question, and loaded everything I see in the Reference list in my VS WinForm project.  If the WinForm app works I wonder what else could be missing.  Does the error message mean some other unnamed assembly even though it says Aforge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "AForge.Imaging.dll" library depends on the following libraries that must also be loaded;

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Drawing"
Add-Type -Path "E:\AForge.dll"
Add-Type -Path "E:\AForge.Math.dll"
Add-Type -Path "E:\AForge.Imaging.dll"
```

run the following PowerShell command to list the currently loaded assemblies and verify you have the necessary bits.

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname
```

Here were my results:

```
FullName
--------
AForge, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c1db6ff4eaa06aeb
AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b
AForge.Math, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abba2e25397ee8c9
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.PowerShell.Security, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Microsoft.WSMan.Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Configuration.Install, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

I can confirm this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run `Process Monitor` and check what assembly it is looking for and where. It may be that one of the assemblies needed by AForge.NET cannot be found, or some security limitations. Sometimes similar problems can be if you are trying to load 32 bit version of DLL into 64 bit powershell and vice versa

Comment: I did that and from the >2million entries I found a couple that might be relevant: RegOpenKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion\PublisherPolicyPolicy\Default\v4.0_policy.2.2.AForge__c1db6ff4eaa06aeb NAME NOT FOUND.  Another was exactly the same but less the substring "v4.0_".

Answer (score 0):

Install aforge.video in project from where you are calling function- Following is the syntax for nuget console
Install-Package AForge.Video -Project "ProjectNameFromWhichAforgeFunctionCalls" -Version 2.2.4.0

This solved my problem