# Binding Redirection in Azure Automation Account PowerShell Runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, redirect, binding

I'm in need of some help in setting up PowerShell binding redirection within an Azure Automation Account Runbook.

Essentially my Runbook calls a number of methods within two 3rd party .Net dlls, both provided by the same author. One of the dlls has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json V12.0.1 and the other has a dependency on IdentityModel V4.0.0 which in turn has a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json V11.0.2. My Azure environment uses Windows PowerShell Desktop V5.1.15063.726. Before I do any work in my Runbook I call a function that loads all of the dlls in my imported module (the function calls the [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom() method for each dll). I have verified that my imported dlls, including the Newtonsoft.Json.dll V12.0.1 have loaded successfully.

As expected, when Runbook execution hits a line that calls one of the 3rd party dll methods that needs the IdentityModel.dll an exception is thrown:
Exception calling "GetResult" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

This is a known issue and the consensus so far seems to be that I need to create and attach an event handler in PowerShell. One of the proposed solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268475/resolving-assembly-dependency-references-with-powershell). My problem is with the line that attempts to attach the handler:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)
```

When my Runbook hits this line the following exception is thrown:
Cannot find an overload for "add_AssemblyResolve" and the argument count: "1". TargetSite: Void CheckActionPreference(System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionContext, System.Exception) StackTrace: at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)

I can confirm that very limited testing seems to prove the code works in Windows 8.1 using the PowerShell ISE. I have searched extensively to see if there is a difference between how this code should be written in Azure and Windows Desktop, but no luck. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Am I missing any DLLs or using statements from my PowerShell script? If it is not possible to redirect binding in this way can anyone help with an alternative technique?

A code extract showing the creation and attachment of the event handler follows:

```
# Intercept resolution of binaries
$onAssemblyResolveEventHandler = [System.ResolveEventHandler]
{
    param($sender, $e)

    Write-Host "ResolveEventHandler: Attempting FullName resolution of $($e.Name)" 
    foreach($assembly in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) 
    {
        if ($assembly.FullName -eq $e.Name)
        {
            Write-Host "Successful FullName resolution of $($e.Name)" 
            return $assembly
        }
    }

    Write-Host "ResolveEventHandler: Attempting name-only resolution of $($e.Name)" 
    foreach($assembly in [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        # Get just the name from the FullName (no version)
        $assemblyName = $assembly.FullName.Substring(0, $assembly.FullName.IndexOf(", "))

        if ($e.Name.StartsWith($($assemblyName + ","))) 
        {
            Write-Host "Successful name-only (no version) resolution of $assemblyName" 
            return $assembly
        }
    }

   Write-Host "Unable to resolve $($e.Name)" 
    return $null
}   
# Attach event handler
# This is the line that fails.
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.add_AssemblyResolve($onAssemblyResolveEventHandler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to resolve the problem with getting binding redirection working in an Azure Automation Account - PowerShell runbook environment, but the author of the two 3rd party .Net dlls has kindly agreed to use NewtonSoft.Json version 11.0.2 for both dlls, so my problem disappears.

Comment: Hello, if you resolved your question, you should mark your own answer as accepted.